# Workbook_BeforeClose MsgBox Bug

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to create a control that requires a user to enter information in a specific cell before they close the workbook. If the cell is empty when the users attempts to close then they should be prompted to either stay in the workbook and enter information or exit without saving. If the cell is populated then the workbook should automatically save itself.

Below is what I managed to come up with so far, placed in the ThisWorkbook object. The issue I'm having is that after the MsgBox appears and an option is selected, it then reappears a second time. I can't work out why this is happening so hopefully someone on here can point out what it is I'm missing.

Note, I only want the current active workbook to close, not the entire application to quit. So if the user has other Excel windows open I don't want those to get closed also.

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    If Range(“A1”).Value = “” Then
        OutPut = Msgbox (“A1 is empty. Exit without saving?”, vbOKCancel + vbDefaultButton2)
        If OutPut = 1 Then
            ThisWorkbook.Close False
        Else: Cancel = True
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If
ActiveWorkbook.Save
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you *do* try to close the workbook again using `ThisWorkbook.Close False`, that's where the second event originates from.

Instead, use `ThisWorkbook.Saved = True` to prevent the confirmation dialog to pop up:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Dim OutPut As VbMsgBoxResult

    If Range("A1").Value = "" Then
        OutPut = MsgBox("A1 is empty. Exit without saving?", vbOKCancel + vbDefaultButton2)
        If OutPut = vbOK Then
            ThisWorkbook.Saved = True
        Else
            Cancel = True
        End If
    Else
        ThisWorkbook.Save
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: That was it! Thanks a bunch, knew it'd be something simple!